# Do I say えいがにみました or えいがをみました　？

Tags: particle-に, particle-を

Do I say えいが**に**みました or えいが**を**みました？

Answer (score 8):

With this class of perception verbs, the thing you are perceiving is the **direct object**.  We mark it as a direct object using the **accusative case particle を**:

> 映画【えいが】**を**見ました【みました】

Other verbs in this class include 聞く【きく】 'hear' and 嗅ぐ【かぐ】 'smell'.

---

We would make it a direct object in English, too, by the way:

> I saw **a movie**.

Except that in English, we mark the direct object by its position in the sentence.  In Japanese, you use the accusative case particle を instead.

Comment: Though 映画に見ました is valid for 'I saw it in a movie'.

Comment: Isn't で used for that? (映画で見た)?

Comment: (Flaw created [a question for に見る vs で見る](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19161/%E3%81%AB-vs-%E3%81%A7-%E6%98%A0%E7%94%BB%E3%81%AB%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B-vs-%E6%98%A0%E7%94%BB%E3%81%A7%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B))