# Can you use で to refer to abstract locations?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-で

This is probably a pretty basic question, but I'm having trouble finding an answer both here and with Google:

Can you use 「で」to refer to abstract locations, like "in the video" or "on twitter"?

Here are two examples of sentences I've constructed, but am unsure about:

(1) 「ツイッターでビデオをみました。」 - I saw the video on Twitter.

(2) 「ビデオでなにをしていましたか？」 - What were you doing in the video?

If で is not the correct particle to use in these situations, is there another particle that is more suitable? Or would you phrase these sentences completely differently?

Comment: [This answer may be related](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19163/542)

Comment: Hi! Looks like I didn't do a good enough job searching - that answer was quite helpful and gives me a good sense that my two proposed sentences are OK. Is there anything I should do to close down this question?